# Jordan Canonical Form of I + xy*

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $x, y$ be column matrices of complex numbers. If $y^*x$ is not zero, determine the Jordan canonical form of $A = I + xy^*$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that 
$$
(xy^*)v = x(y^*v) = \langle v,y\rangle x
$$
We note that $\ker(xy^*) = \{v : \langle v,y\rangle = 0\}$, and that 
$$
(xy^*)x = \langle x,y\rangle x
$$
Which means that we have established an eigenbasis of $xy^*$. Conclude that $xy^*$ has the Jordan canonical form
$$
J = 
\pmatrix{
\langle x,y\rangle & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & & \cdots & 0
}
$$
So that with $J$ as above, we have $xy^* = SJS^{-1}$ for some invertible $S$. It follows that 
$$
A = I + SJS^{-1} = S(I + J)S^{-1}
$$
Which means that $A$ has Jordan canonical form $I + J$.

Comment: Ah... I see. I am having troubles figuring out what it would look like. I am new to this concept and barely understanding the concept.

Thank you for answering this.

Comment: How do we know there are no ones on the superdiagonal of the Jordan form?

Comment: @milez as I explain in my answer, $A$ has an eigenbasis.  This necessarily means that $A$ is diagonalizable, which is to say that the Jordan form will be diagonal.